# Getting Information from a Collider to another method

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I have 3 Game Objects that have a trigger collider on them as well as a script called DetectCollision.cs  with the following code:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        string Name = "";
        Name = col.gameObject.name;

    }
```

I would like to pass the name of the object that collides with the object to another method that will add the names together of the collided object.
for example: place holder 1 collides with a gameobject called A, place holder 2 collides with a gameobject called b, place holder 3 collides with a gameobject called c ... would like to send the names of the collided objects to another method to add the strings to make the word - ABC.

any tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what your question meant but im assuming you want to call another class method to store the strings so im writing this

For that you will need to create a class with static instance

```
public class ClassToStoreInfo : MonoBehaviour {
    public static ClassToStoreInfo thisInstance;
    private string CollisionLine = "";
    void Start() {
        thisInstance = this;
    }

    public void AddStringAfterCollision(string value) {
        CollisionLine += value;
    }
}
```

then call that class static variable within your collider function

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
    string Name = "";
    Name = col.gameObject.name;
    ClassToStoreInfo.thisInstance.AddStringAfterCollision(Name);
}
```

you can also call the above class in your script and keep a reference of it instead of using static variable for the class instance. Hope this helps.